# How do I hint to Couchbase schema-inference to use my "type" field?

Tags: couchbase, jsonschema

Couchbase [can infer](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/infer.html) the implicit  schema(s) of the documents in a bucket.  (Also see [this article](https://blog.couchbase.com/auto-schema-discovery/).)

A common design pattern is to have a `_type` field (or `type`, `class`, `table` etc). Naturally the implicit schema will often differ based on this; these are called "flavors" by the inference engine.

In my bucket, Couchbase did not identify the `_type` attribute as the determinant of flavors. Is there a way that I can hint to `INFER` to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way that INFER works is it samples the documents (randomly). If most of your documents have this attribute, I would expect INFER to pick that up. If only a small percentage have the _type field, then INFER might not figure it out.

You can increase the sample size in INFER (the default is 1000 documents):

```
INFER `mybucket` WITH {"sample_size": 2000};
```

It will take longer, of course.

I don't think there is a way to give `INFER` hints to look at specific fields.

Comment: Every document has the _type field and this was not used by INFER to distinguish flavors. Maybe because my bucket , in  this preliminary trial,  had only a few different types. But I guess I'll have to keep  experimenting.